# Find String in a txt file using Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a .txt file that is rather large--roughly 70K lines.

I'm trying to use Python to find all the instances of the string "Cannot update".

When I open the file and use ctrl-f on "Cannot update" it instantly finds it; however, when using RegEx in Python, .find(), or if in, it simply cannot find the string. Please see three methods I have used below:

RegEx method:

```
f = open('C:\PerfupD.txt', 'r')

strings = re.findall('Cannot update', f.read())

print(strings)
```

.find():

```
with open('C:\PerfUpD.txt', 'r') as file:

    for line in file:

          if line.find('Cannot update') != -1:

              print("Errors found")
```

if in:

```
with open('C:\PerfUpD.txt', 'r') as file:

    for line in file:

          if 'Cannot update' in line:

              print("Errors found")
```

I even tried searching for "Ca" and it can't find anything, but when I just search "C" it finds tons of instances...One side note is that this .txt file is generated from a website that initially saves the file as a .err file. I then save it as .txt.

The only thing I can think of is that perhaps the data in the file is generated in some other form but looks like regular text when open. Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: All 3 methods should work. Can you post an extract of your input file? I suspect either a case problem or the space character which is non-standard or maybe doubled.

Comment: is it possible the path to the file is off? Can you print all the lines of the file without any issues?

Comment: I just stepped out but will do so asap. Just FYI, I am pretty good with vba and wrote a macro to copy each line in the txt file and paste it to cells but it prints nothing to the cells...

Comment: check [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536818/find-string-in-a-txt-file-using-python/40537121#40537121](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40536818/find-string-in-a-txt-file-using-python/40537121#40537121) answer below. Basically you have a logical error in your code. the find() returns -1 when a string is found.

Comment: Small extract:
Skipping zzzzzz portfolio because close date is 07-11-16.  Processing Security Type Group (by Currency).
Skipping zzzzzz  portfolio because close date is 01-22-16.  Processing Security Type Group (by Currency).
zzzzzz performance (rollup) was not updated.  zzzzzz performance (rollup) cannot be read or the report date range is prior to the portfolio's start date.
Cannot update zzzzzz  portfolio because close date is 11-07-16.  Processing Security Type Group (by Currency).

Comment: It's strange because when I create a .txt file with my code it works. But it will not work on the .err file saved as a .txt. I think it has to be something with the data type generated from the .err file. It looks like a normal string but somehow is not...

Comment: It also might be worth noting that the language that generates the original report is C. I believe when "printf" is used in C it affects how Python reads a strings.

Answer (score 0):

you could probably just do this:

```
f = open('your file.txt', 'r+')
for line in f:
    if 'Cannot Update' in line:
        print('error found')
```

no need for regex